# finding a element in web page with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find link on a web page which has class property and/or id property and/or href property.

So at design time I would not know what properties that link would have. It could have either one or any two or all three properties.

After studying I have figured out to find an element with href in jquery the following code works-

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']")
```

Similarly finding an a element with id and class also works.

What I would like to figure out is howto find out an element which has a href of value 'http://www.google.com/' and/or class value of 'abc' and/or id value of 'xyz'

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma (`,`) to join selectors together in an `OR`-like fashion:

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com'], a.abc, a#xyz")
```

Comment: how do I do AND -like.. with href and class OR href and id OR href,class and id, the class and id works- $("a#country.save")