# Finding number of links on page which link to same

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a continuation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270270/finding-a-element-in-web-page-with-multiple-properties/)

I need to find the number of links on a page which link to 'www.google.com' and have class 'abc'

Thanks

Comment: `var count = $("a.abc[href='http://www.google.com/']").length`?

Comment: @TimSeguine I'm a javascript newbie, searched for this, could not get any results on web, maybe was asking the wrong question

Comment: @ArunPJohny Tx- sincerely appreciate..

Comment: @Arnab Yeah, I decided I was being a bit too harsh with my comment, so I deleted it. That said, I think you would probably benefit quite a bit from reading a book or two on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd use:

```
$('a.abc[href$="www.google.com"], a.abc[href$="www.google.com/"]').length
```

This will match any `a` element with a class of "abc" which has a `href` *ending in* `www.google.com` or `www.google.com/`.

Answer (score 1):

Use chaining of attribute-value selector with class selector:

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com'].abc").length
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/sratL5en/)**

Comment: Please note that meta characters such as `.` need to be escaped or else you quote the "www.google.com"

Comment: @user3558931: its already wrapped in quotes in attribute value selector. you dont have to escape them again.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you've not specified if the link should have/be `www.google.com` the following will catch all links that have the string `www.google.com` and the `a` has class `abc`:

```
var nLinks = $('a[href*="www.google.com"].abc').length;
```

REF:

[**jQuery Attribute Contains API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a custom filter? (also for future scopes):

```
$("a.abc").filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr("href") == "http://google.it";
}).length;
```

If the methods returns true the element is selected, otherwise not, simply and easy to use!